# How can I trigger a notification based on a condition in react native?

Tags: react-native, localnotification, react-native-push-notification

Hello stack overflow community,

Hope everyone is doing well,

I'm new in react native and I'm stuck with react native notifications, I want to trigger a notification based on a condition:
**(condition)? {trigger notification}:{false}**

Thank you in advance,

Comment: what's your problem here?

Comment: thanks for answering me! this is the error I get:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {triggerLocalNotificationHandler}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Post some code you have written so far ;)

Comment: const triggerLocalNotificationHandler = () => {
        Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
        content: {
            title: "Local Notification",
            body: "Hello this is a local notification!",
        },
        trigger: { seconds: 1 },
        })
    }
    const {x, y} = limit;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>
                {x > y ? {triggerLocalNotificationHandler} : 'false'}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )

Comment: you can't render a function in the Text component

Comment: so have you an idea what should I do instead?

Comment: why you render the function in the Text component? what condition you want to trigger the function?

Comment: I just need to trigger a notification when x is higher than y but dunno how to code it!

Comment: It would be great if you can post the full code snippet in the original post